# Service doesn't start alarm after closing the app

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, alarm

I want to create an alarm application, which will sound the alarm when you set the time. I've got it to work partially. I'm stuck at the alarm not being set after the app is closed via recent tray(Not with force stop). To tackle this, I created a service which will run in the background(even if the app is closed) and will sound the alarm.

My problem right now, is that even after using a service, I'm unable to sound the alarm after the app is closed. However, the service seems to be running after the closure of the app(I've seen in running apps. It says My App has a service running in the background).

NOTE : I've also bound the service with my activity so that I can use its methods.

NOTE 2 : The service sounds the alarm when the application is open, Only fails to do so when the app is closed.

This is my code :

Calling the service from my Activity :

```
    public void startOnClick(View view) {

        int aHour = alarmTimePicker.getCurrentHour();
        int aMin = alarmTimePicker.getCurrentMinute();
        Alarms alarm = new Alarms(aHour, aMin); //I've created an Alarms class Seperately
        myService.setAlarm2(alarm); //Setting the alarm via service 
        Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm SET.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

In MyService : `package com.wars.tap.tapwars;

public class MyService extends Service {

```
private final IBinder myBinder = new MyBinder();

Alarms alarm = new Alarms();
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
private AlarmManager alarmManager;
private ServiceCallBacks serviceCallbacks;


public MyService() {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return myBinder;
}

public class MyBinder extends Binder {
    MyService getService() {
        return MyService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}

public void setCallbacks(ServiceCallBacks callbacks) {
    serviceCallbacks = callbacks;
}


public void setAlarm2(final Alarms alarm){

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarm.get_hour());
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarm.get_min());

                AlarmManager AM = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Intent i = new Intent(MyService.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MyService.this, 934, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                AM.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);


            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    };
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.start();
}
}
```

`

So, the setAlarm2 is the method I'm using in the service to sound the alarm. It's working when the app is open, but fails to work when the app is being closed. As you can see, this is my first post on StackOverflow and I'm also new to android programming. I've been stuck with this for a long time and would appreciate some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your alarm could be working, but the notification center is not aware of allowing your app any privileges to highlight the event that is occurring. Check out this link [here](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html) for details on Notifications.

**EDIT**

Check out the code below I extracted from a previous project. I left out the necessary parts:

```
public class MyClass extends Service {

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
  }
  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
  }
  @Nullable
  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
  }
  public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    // Input your code here prior to exit.
    stopSelf();
  }
}
```

Comment: I already have a AlarmService class which sends and manages the notifications. It's called within the AlarmReceiver class.

Comment: Been stuck with it for a while now. Any help?

Comment: hi @S.A.Nik i'm having the same problem have you found any solution?